# How to call a java method from jsp by clicking a menu in html page?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I wrote a server program in java but in order to give an interface with web i want to access   java method in jsp when certain menu button is clicked. How can i do this?

Comment: Related: [How to use servlets and ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 5):

Using ajax (using [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), you could make a request to server, In your case may be to a `Servlet`  which will invoke method on server that you requested

**For example:**

```
function callMe(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/someServlet",
      data: { methodToInvoke: "sayHello" , data: "Abc" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
      alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
    });
}
```

at `Servlet` end

```
doPost(...){
 String methodToCall = request.getParameter("methodToCall");
 //do some stuff to determine method to call and call it like
 methodService.invoke(request.getParameter("data"));
}
```

**Also See**

- [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org)

Comment: probably i made a mistake as it is for server side i shouldn't use jsp. thanks for answering

Comment: So does it answer your question ?

Comment: actually now i may use Quercus to make bridge between java and php.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do this directly because JSP is server side and html is client side. However, it can be accomplished via AJAX. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)