# How can I call doPost() method of servlet from <a href> tag in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, hyperlink, http-post

I would like to call `doPost()` method of a servlet from `<a href>`, but it calls `doGet()` method. How can I call to `doPost()` method?

This is my code.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

    <li><a href="newAdmin" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> New Admin</a></li>

    <li><a href="index.jsp"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> LogOut</a></li>

  </ul>
```

`newAdmin` is the url pattern of my servlet and I would like to call `doPost()` of that servlet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: use javascript, ajax call

Comment: If you want to invoke HTTP `POST` from the link, you need to use JavaScript for `POST`ing the form. The answers to [How to call doPost() servlet from a hyperlink in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287642/how-to-call-dopost-servlet-from-a-hyperlink-in-jsp) should help you forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a form submission instead of an anchor. This should get you started - [W3 schools - form tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp). For example:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li><a href="newAdmin" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> New Admin</a></li>

<li><form method="POST" action="index.jsp"><button type="submit"> LogOut</button></form></li>
```

However you can't have a span tag inside a button so you might have to use javascript to submit the form instead of a button (attach a click function to your glyphicon that submits the form).