# Call a doPost method along with a url of a page in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, servlet-3.0

Example:
`window.open("LoginServlet", "_self");`

This code will make the browser to redirect to LoginSevlet but it executes doGet method of Servlet but I want to execute the doPost method.

Is there any way through which I can directly execute the doPost method of LoginServlet?

Comment: Do you have separate logic for `doGet` than `doPost`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call doPost() servlet from a hyperlink in jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287642/how-to-call-dopost-servlet-from-a-hyperlink-in-jsp)

Comment: yes i have separate logic @user7294900

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click a form with `target="_self"` and `method="post"`:

```
 <form name="postForm" method="post" action="LoginServlet" target="_self">
 </form>
```

And submit it instead of `window.open`:

```
 document.forms["postForm"].submit();
```