# Sending data to servlet from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

This is a more can I, then a how to question. When I send data to a servlet, and they are both on the same domain, I use :

```
$.post('action.do', {arrayData:myArray, mode:"insert"});
```

or something similar. If, for example, I have html running within an android app on my device and I have a server in the cloud, can I perform something such as :

```
$.post('http://www.example.com/action.do', {arrayData:myArray, mode:"insert"});
```

Where example.com is the domain I have the server on, is this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "http://www.example.com/action.do",
  data: { param1: "cal1" , param2: "val2" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

**See Also**

- [How to call a java method from jsp by clicking a menu in html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983961/how-to-call-a-java-method-from-jsp-by-clicking-a-menu-in-html-page)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You just cannot post to a server sitting on another domain, it's prevented by Ajax cross-domain policy of many browsers.